# PHP script to send email from form

Tags: php

Can someone please tell me how to fix this script so the form info is sent to the correct email (i.e., my email....lets assume my email is username@mydomain.net). I would like the email to show the user's email addrress who sent to to me as well.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['fldName'];
$email = $_POST['fldEmail'];
$phone = $_POST['fldPhone'];
$comments = $_POST['fldComments'];
$isFormValid = false; 

if (strlen($name) && strlen($email) && strlen($phone) && strlen($comments)) $isFormValid = true; 

if ($isFormValid) 

{ 


$to      = 'username@mydomain.net'; 
$subject = 'Contact Us Form Comments'; 

$message = 'Name: '.$name."\r\n".'Email: '.$email."\r\n".'Comments: '.$comments; 

$headers = 'From: username@domain.net' . "\r\n" 
         . 'Reply-To: username@mydomain.net' . "\r\n"; 

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

header("location: thankyou.html");

} 
else 
{ 

echo "Please fill in the required fields"; 

} 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using native PHP mail() to do everything by yourself, it is better off you use some useful library like swift mailer, which makes it very easier for you to send mail without having to worry about the inner workings.

for example to send a mail in swift mailer all you need to do is.

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.example.org', 25)
  ->setUsername('your username')
  ->setPassword('your password');
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself');
// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

you can find more information about swift mailer in there official website http://swiftmailer.org/

Answer (score 1):

This `$headers = 'From: username@domain.net' . "\r\n"` will display who sent you the email. It's already there in your script. You don't need to add anything extra

Comment: That email that is currently there is ours. I need it to be the person who filled out the form. So how do i add their email address from the form?

Answer (score 0):

Change out the `$headers` variable to use the sender's email address instead of your own.

Comment: I dont know the user's email address, as its real time when they are filling out the form. Shouldn't it be a vaiable or something?

Comment: maybe?????? but where do i put it? In the code I posted in my question, how can i be sure that the email i receive has the person's email address in the correct spot (NOT MINE), so when i reply to the email, the email has their address in the TO field, and not mine

Comment: See where you put your email address in the `From` and `Reply-To`? Just substitute those with the sender's address.